# table view.reloadData() doesn't work within the table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, reloaddata, pull-to-refresh

table view.reloadData() updates the table view after I change view controller and I come back. I add a pull to refresh functionality :

```
    lazy var refreshControl: UIRefreshControl = {
    let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "handleRefresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    refreshControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
//        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
//            self.tableView.reloadData()
//        })
    return refreshControl
    }()
```

this is outside any methods. Then in the viewdidload():

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.tableView.addSubview(self.refreshControl)
 }
```

The handleRefresh function is this:

```
    func handleRefresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {
    // Do some reloading of data and update the table view's data source
    // Fetch more objects from a web service, for example...
    fetch()    // Fetches new data

    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

This works,but only after I exit the view controller and come back. I think the problem is that the array that use to populate the tableview cells is a global array, meaning that it is declared in the same scope as the import statements, but I'm not sure. I would like some advice on how to make the pull to refresh "refresh" the table view as soon as it is pulled.

This is my fetch code:

```
func fetch(){
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Photo")
    query.whereKey("friend", equalTo:"bob")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            self.getImageData(objects as [PFObject])
            if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                PhotoInfoArray = objects  // This is the global array that stores photo information, date created, etc.
            }
        } else {
            println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
        }
    }
}

func getImageData(objects: [PFObject]) {
    for object in objects {

        let thumbNail = object["Image"] as PFFile


        thumbNail.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock({
            (imageData: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                let image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                //image object implementation
                imageArray.append(image!)// this is the global array that stores the actual pictures
                //                    println(image)
            }

        })//getDataInBackgroundWithBlock - end
    }//for - end
}
```

These functions use Parse as a backend.

Comment: Your fetch call is most probably async so when your code hits reloadData the data has not been received yet. Your current code is depending on synchronous execution. So you want to do the reloadData call in callback (or delegate method) of your fetch call. Maybe look into blocks that's perfect for these kind of things.

Comment: uhhh I mean closures of course (blocks are Objective-C ;) )

Comment: Thank you for responding. What does "async" mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it might be a good idea to keep track of what is actually in your array because I have never seen a scenario where           self.tableView.reloadData() doesn't work.
I'd advise to print the array in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear.

Maybe it might be handy to add a success call then if you need to wait for some other process to finish like so:

```
    func someFunction(success: ((success: Bool) -> Void))) {
        //Perform some tasks here
        success(success: true)
    }
```

And then in the viewcontroller expecting the results it would look like this:

```
    someFunction({ (bool) -> Void in 
       if bool {
          self.tableView.reloadData()
       }
    })
```

Comment: That's true, every tutorial almost seem to use reloadData() randomly and it works seemlesly. I think that it might be that the calls don't follow the main thread, so it waits in the background.

Answer (score 0):

tableView Has inbuilt functionality to reload it,in first view will appear first 20 items are loaded and than , when your are scroll table than another 20 items are loaded in to table ,all methods are call again. so don't need to use refresh.

Answer (score 0):

Your fetch call is most probably asynchronous (so done in the background) so when your code hits reloadData the data has not been received yet. Your current code is depending on synchronous execution. 
So you want to do the reloadData call in callback (or delegate method) of your fetch call. Maybe look into closures that's perfect for these kind of things. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html

Maybe you can show some of your fetching code..